# Cypress: asserting elements within the same parent element

Tags: cypress

Suppose I have the following page:

```
<div>
    <div class="item">
        <p data-testid=title>Item One Title</p>
        <p data-testid=subtitle>Item One Subtitle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p data-testid=title>Item Two Title</p>
        <p data-testid=subtitle>Item Two Subtitle</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to test that `Item One Title` and `Item One Subtitle` are present within the same parent `div.item`. What would be the best way to do this in Cypress?

What I tried so far:

**Test #1:**

```
cy.get('[data-testid=title]').should('contain.text', 'Item One Title');
cy.get('[data-testid=subtitle]').should('contain.text', 'Item One Subtitle');
```

These tests will pass, but does not check that `Item One Title` and `Item One Subtitle` are within the same parent `div`.

**Test #2:**

```
cy.get('[data-testid=title]').should('contain.text', 'Item One Title').then(($foo) => {
   cy.wrap($foo).next().should('contain.text', 'Item One Subtitle');
});
```

Seems to be the same as Test #1, does not check that `Item One Title` and `Item One Subtitle` are within the same parent `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.parent()` selector looks suitable

```js
cy.contains('[data-testid=title]', 'Item One Title')
  .parent()
  .should('contain', 'Item One Subtitle');
```

or use the parent directly

```js
cy.contains('div.item', 'Item One Title')
  .should('contain', 'Item One Subtitle');
```

Comment: I ended up using the first solution, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `siblings`

```js
cy.contains('[data-testid=title]', 'Item One Title')
  .siblings()
  .should('have.attr', 'data-testid', 'subtitle')
  .and('contain.text', 'Item One Subtitle')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `data-testid` attr to the item `div` element are looking to verify or do the following.

```
// swap div with [data-testid=item] if you add it to item div
cy.contains('div', 'Item One Title')
  .within( () => {
    // all queries will only be subject to the item div with 'Item One Title' text
    cy.get('[data-testid=title]').should('contain.text', 'Item One Title');
    cy.get('[data-testid=subtitle]').should('contain.text', 'Item One Subtitle');
   })
```